# How do I deploy a Pod initializer without deadlocking?

Tags: kubernetes

I created an InitializerConfiguration that adds my initializer for pods.

The documentation says to use a Deployment (https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/#configure-initializers-on-the-fly). However, doing so results in my initializer Pod being stuck in "pending" because it's waiting for itself to initialize it. I tried overriding the pending initializers to an empty list in the pod spec of the Deployment, but that seems to be ignored.

What's the correct way to deploy a Pod initializer without deadlocking?

I found a couple bug reports that seem related, but no solutions that worked for me:
* https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/51485 (based on this one I added the "initialize" verb for pods to the ClusterRole system:controller:replicaset-controller, but that didn't help either)

Answer (score 1):

> However, doing so results in my initializer Pod being stuck in "pending" because it's waiting for itself to initialize it

But the docs say:

> You should first deploy the initializer controller and make sure that it is working properly before creating the `initializerConfiguration`. Otherwise, any newly created resources will be stuck in an uninitialized state.

So it sounds to me like you will want to `kubectl delete initializerConfiguration --all` (or, of course, the specific name of the `initializerConfiguration`), allow your initializer Pod to start successfully, **then** `kubectl create -f my-initializer-config.yaml` or whatever.

Comment: That does work. However, if my initializer pod is killed and gets recreated, then it will deadlock again

Comment: Sure, I would suspect that's why they recommend a `Deployment`, so you can very easily run more than one of them. I'd have to test it to know for sure, but you might also try using a "static" `Pod`, by placing the YAML in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests` on a `Node` to see if those are exempted from the `iC`

Comment: Ya, but what I'd be concerned about is the cluster going down and then not being able to recover because none of the Deployment pods can start. Ah ya, hadn't thought of the static Pods, I might try that, although it doesn't fit in great with our clusters since we don't need them at all now

Comment: _since we don't need them at all now_ then how are you running the apiserver, controller-manager, any CNI servers, et al? Are they [not managed by kubelet](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray/blob/v2.5.0/roles/kubernetes/master/templates/manifests/kube-apiserver.manifest.j2)?

Comment: well, I guess the good news is that whatever configuration management system owns the `systemd` descriptors for the control plane could own the static pod descriptors for the `iC` (assuming that trick works)